# Theorem 2-7 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak. I rewrote the proof for me. Is my proof logically ok?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, partial-derivative

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

[image: Text]

I read this proof by the author.
I felt the proof is not logically clear.
So, I rewrote the proof for me.
Is my proof logically ok?

> Suppose first that $m=1$, so that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}.$ Define $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by $h(x)=(a^1,\dots,x,\dots,a^n),$ with $x$ in the $j$th place. Since $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $h$ is differentiable at $a^j$, $f\circ h$ is differentiable at $a^j$ by Chain Rule (Theorem 2-2).  Since $(f\circ h)^{'}(a^j)$ exists and $$\begin{align*}D_jf(a)&=\lim_{x^j\to a^j} \frac{f(a^1,\dots,x^j,\dots,a^n)-f(a^1,\dots,a^j,\dots,a^n)}{x^j-a^j} \\\\
> &=\lim_{x^j\to a^j} \frac{f\circ h(x^j)-f\circ h(a^j)}{x^j-a^j} \\\\
> &=(f\circ h)^{'}(a^j),\end{align*}$$ $D_jf(a)$ exists.
> By Theorem 2-2, $$\begin{align*}(f\circ h)^{'}(a^j)&=f^{'}(a)\cdot h^{'}(a^j) \\\\
> &=f^{'}(a)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0 \\\\ \vdots \\\\ 1\\\\ \vdots \\\\ 0\end{pmatrix}．\end{align*}$$ Since $(f\circ h)^{'}(a^j)$ has the single entry $D_jf(a)$, this shows that $D_jf(a)$ is the $j$th entry of the $1\times n$ matrix $f^{'}(a)$.
> The theorem now follows for arbitrary $m$ since, by Theorem 2-3, each $f^i$ is differentiable and the $i$th row of $f^{'}(a)$ is $(f^i)^{'}(a)$.

Comment: Is there any other change besides the two limits? This book is nicely written. Things are there. One just need to keep close attention. Right after the definition of partial derivative, there is the observation that $D_if(a)$ is the derivative of $g(x)=f(a^1,\ldots,x,\ldots,a^n)$. This $g$ is $f\circ h$. They write $D_if(a)=g'(a^i)$.  This is the equation $D_jf(a)=(f\circ h)'(a^j)$. As you see, the explanation of this equation is not inside the proof, because it was already explained earlier.

Comment: @user85667 Thank you very much for your comment.